# How can I make my dumb TV bed lift smart?

Tags: smart-home, hardware, microcontrollers

I'm an experienced developer who is looking to make the foray into IoT hardware. I have written applications in C and C++ in the past and I'm currently interested in Rust. I have little to no experience in electronic device development. I have a TV bed with a soundbar built into the footboard. The soundbar remote operates the  TV lift, but with the following caveats:

- The soundbar has to be switched on in order to operate the lift
- There's a 10-12 second delay after switching on the soundbar before it will respond to the remote control

This can be *mildly* frustrating at times when the TV has been left up and the soundbar has auto-powered off. Fumble for the remote, power on the soundbar, wait 10-12 seconds. I'm too impatient for that! So, I thought this may make a first good project, with more minor frustrations to fix with other projects in the future if I am successful.

The soundbar connects to the TV lift control box via 3 wires (green, white, black) glued into a 4-pin connector (A, see photo below diagram). The control box is has a connector (B) that splits, with one cable going to the AC adapter and the other to the TV lift mechanism.

I'm thinking that the least intrusive approach is to have my IoT device sit as an intermediary between the soundbar and the TV lift control box, replicating the behaviour of those 3 wires in the connector (A). I would look to use MQTT over WiFi or Bluetooth, connected to Home Assistant (which I'm already using extensively), to send the raise/lower commands.

So, with that in mind:

1. How do I figure out what those wires do?
2. I have an old Raspberry Pi 2B collecting dust (and some Bluetooth/WiFi dongles), is it suitable for this? If not, what is recommended?
3. How can I get started on the programming side?

[image: connections diagram]

[image: connector A]

Comment: there is nothing relating to IoT in your question ... the IoT part comes after the TV lift works as desired

Comment: You first need a multimeter to find out what each wire is (possibly GND, VCC and signal, or maybe GND, up signal, down signal, but I would expect a return signal as well) and the signal levels (e.g. 5V, 12V…). Then a logic analyser to observe what is sent (and possibly received), which may be something very simple on/off or something a bit more subtle like SPI or I2C, or even some proprietary protocol. Once you know what it does you can try to replicate it. Note that from the diagram there are at least two places you could insert your device, on either side of the control box, A or B.

Comment: At the stage, the question may be more suitable for electronics.stackexchange.com but check out the posting guidelines before you do, they sometimes have acute close-question-itis over there.

Comment: @jcaron thanks for the detailed info, I'll do some research and ask there